# Is there any difference between Quiet and Internal`DeactivateMessages?

Tags: undocumented, message-coding

Both `Quiet` and `` Internal`DeactivateMessages `` seem to suppress error messages.  Does anyone have any experience with them and found any real differences?

Comment: I don't know what the difference are, but `Quiet` is invalid in parallel calculations. Maybe you can exam if the later one is invalid as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`` Internal`DeactivateMessages[expr, msg1, msg2, ...] `` evaluates `expr` after turning off the given messages. When the second argument is not present (or `All`) then `expr` is evaluated in a special mode that does not generate any messages.

An example of a difference would be

```
Internal`DeactivateMessages[On[Power::infy]; 1/0, Power::infy]

(* gives a message *)

Quiet[On[Power::infy]; 1/0, Power::infy]

(* does not give a message *)
```

`` Internal`DeactivateMessages `` is the older and the simpler function. `Quiet` has been introduced in version 6.0 and is more sophisticated, as it also has the form

```
Quiet[expr, msgoff, msgon]
```

indicating that the messages in the list `msgoff` should not be generated, but those in `msgon` should be. Since there can be arbitrary nesting, `Quiet` acts similarly to a scoping construct, keeping track of the wanted/unwanted messages at each level.

I think the main reason `` Internal`DeactivateMessages `` still exists is backward compatibility. There should be no advantage in using it instead of the documented `Quiet`.